# Matrix Exponential for Rotations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-exponential

Are the matrix exponentials of real skew-symmetric matrices always rotations? Does that mean that when we have any real skew-symmetric matrix in n-Dimensions, we can form a rotation around the corresponding rotational-axis by calculating the matrix exponential? Is this equal to the Rodrigues-Formula for 3x3?

Comment: If $A$ is skew then it's easy to show that its exponential is orthogonal $$\large{\exp(A)^T=\exp(A^T)=\exp(-A)=\exp(A)^{-1}}$$
The Rodrigues formula is a scaled/parameterized version of this idea.